# Android Studio 3.0.0 unable to start daemon process

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-gradle-3.0

I tried everything i can to change gradle file but still I have this Error, I can't run new project or old one.

> Error:Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be
>   caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an
>   unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide
>   chapter on the daemon at
>   https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Please read
>   the following process output to find out more:
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not create service of type DaemonContext using DaemonServices.createDaemonContext().
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I'm using Android studio version 3.0.0 on win 10 (64 bit) . distributionUrl=\ https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

### output

```
             2017-10-29 10:25:33,563 [ thread 92]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Please read the following process output to find out more:
                -----------------------

                FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

                * What went wrong: Could not create service of type DaemonContext using DaemonServices.createDaemonContext().

                * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

                * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Please read the following process output to find out more:
                -----------------------

                FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

                * What went wrong: Could not create service of type DaemonContext using DaemonServices.createDaemonContext().

                * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

                * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:85)    
            at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:414) 
                at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:158) 
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:906) 
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:886)     
      at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:218)   
     at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:139)   
     at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)    
       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37) 
 at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59) 
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)   at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)     at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:66)    
  at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:139)   
 at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:125) 
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:388)   
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:445)   
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726) 
            at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)     
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)     
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501) 
            at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66) 
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)  
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)   
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)  at 
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example,
 an unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
```

Comment: What the output of command `gradlew.bat assembleDebug --debug`?

Comment: u have any idea about this error?

Comment: Do you have multiple installation of jdk?

Comment: now,yes JDK 8.152 , 9.0.1 but before that I had only 9.0.1 and didn't work.I even reinstall the Studio and not work.

Comment: Have you choosed the jdk inside the Android Studio? The Android Studio need to know which JDK that they will be used in build and compile.

Comment: I think I didn't,.....................I used it,should I change it ?

Comment: It Work now for JDK 8,thanks for help.